# Wordpress is always on page 1 even though I navigate to second page

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site, where the first page displays fine, the format of the posts are:

1 2

3 4

5

6...etc

I want the second page to display in a single columns, such as:

9

10...etc

I got the first page working perfectly, but when I click on to go to the next page I get the same formatting as the first page, I've tried A LOT of things, creating templates, I created a "If page =>2" which I thought it would do the trick, but it didn't. Then I added

```
<?php  $page  = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  ?>
<h1>page <?php echo $page; ?></h1>
```

To  see what page I was on, and it always displays page one. I have attached the index.php file to http://pastebin.com/gxgWf00Q

You can see the live page at www.popticular.com

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

So, what you need to do is the front page is perfect as i understood you.
Create 2 type of wordpress [custom post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types).

**Method 1:**
In WP admin panel Reading > select landing post **page** layout.
else for 2nd layout

**Method 2**

```
if( get_bloginfo('url')=='your front page url ')
{
1 2

3 4

5

6...etc
}
else
{
9

10...etc
}
```